# Redirecting cout into same file from various sources in c++

Tags: c++, cout, output

my problem is I have a couple of cout's in various files in the project. I would like all of them to be redirected and saved in **.txt** file, and what I achieved by now is that only one cout is saved in the file. I don't want to create separate **.txt** for each **cout**, for the sake of reading them at once. My code looks now like this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream out("out.txt");
    std::cout.rdbuf(out.rdbuf()); 

    std::cout << "get it3";
    std::cout << "get it4"; 
}
```

Both **cout** are in one file, but assuming they are in two different, how to redirect and save in one **.txt**?

Comment: Why not just re-direct standard output at the command line instead of modifying your program ?

Comment: I don't think that it is a good idea. You might want to create some singleton stream, which could be switched everywhere you want, and use it instead of cout

Comment: I have some couts that I'd like to put in file, but not all. @kassak , I don't know about singleton stream creation, can you throw with some example or good reference please?

Comment: I think kassak is suggesting that you make one ostream object which could then be set to be either equivalent to an ofstream or cout (or possibly something else). This is not a bad idea, but considering that you want to only selectively output to a file, it won't work. If the data you want to write to a file is of a specific format, it might be possible by writing a class that detects the format (and selects the stream to use) though.

Comment: What about user-defined literals? (Never to use it for something like this though.) Maybe it's a good idea to define a string type ending on "w" or something. Then you define operator<< for it so that it is written to a file.

Comment: Yes @AnotherTest is right.
If you want simpliest solution this is ok.
Else you could try to find some ready-to-use logging system with severity levels and redirection of them to files/stdout. Or write simple version by yourself. That is not that hard =)

Comment: so there is no simple convenient way for creating some buffer according to this example then? Thanks for those nice ideas, I will make some trials if no solution for this one.

Comment: @AnotherTest no, that is bad. Use stream manipulators http://www.two-sdg.demon.co.uk/curbralan/papers/WritingStreamManipulators.html

Comment: @kassak Yes, that's indeed probably a much better idea.

Comment: @AnotherTest I don't think manipulators are the answer here.  Just replacing the `streambuf` seems to be the simplest and most idiomatic solution: it is the `streambuf` which determines what is done with the characters you output.  (And it's even possible to design streambufs which modify the output; e.g. put a timestamp at the start of each line, or such.)

Comment: I think your immediate question is "I want to use append mode". Minimal change 'std::ofstream out("out.txt",ios_base::app ...);'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious answer is that you should never output to
`std::cout`.  All actual output should be to an `std::ostream&`,
which may be set to `std::cout` by default, but which you can
initialize to other things as well.

Another obvious answer is that redirection should be done before
starting the process.

Supposing, however, that you cannot change the code outputting
to `std::cout`, and that you cannot control the invocation of
your program (or you only want to change some of the outputs),
you can change the output of `std::cout` itself by attaching 
a different `streambuf`.  In this case, I'd use RAII as well, to
ensure that when you exit, `std::cout` has the streambuf it
expects.  But something like the following should work:

```
class TemporaryFilebuf : public std::filebuf
{
    std::ostream&   myStream;
    std::streambuf* mySavedStreambuf;
public:
    TemporaryFilebuf(
            std::ostream& toBeChanged,
            std::string const& filename )
        : std::filebuf( filename.c_str(), std::ios_base::out )
        , myStream( toBeChanged )
        , mySavedStreambuf( toBeChanged.rdbuf() )
    {
        toBeChanged.rdbuf( this );
    }
    ~TemporaryFilebuf()
    {
        myStream.rdbuf( mySavedStreambuf );
    }
};
```

(You'll probably want to add some error handling; e.g. if you
cannot open the file.)

When you enter the zone where you wish to redirect output, just
create an instance with the stream (`std::cout`, or any other
`ostream`) and the name of the file.  When the instance is
destructed, the output stream will resume outputting to
whereever it was outputting before.