# C++ function cout redirect to file

Tags: c++, file, redirect, cout

Say I have a simple function named `print`, with a loop that uses `cout` to print, say, 1-5, to the console.

Is there a way I can do something like:

```
file << print ();
```

To get the output of `print` saved into a file?  Obviously assuming I open the file with `ofstream` properly, and everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `print` is a `void` function with its output hard-coded to `cout`, there is nothing you can do: the output will be controlled by the execution environment's assignment of the output stream (console by default or a file redirect with `>myoutput.txt`).

If you would like your program to control where the output goes, pass `ostream&` to your `print` function, and use it for the output:

```
void print(ostream& ostr) {
    // use ostr instead of cout
    ostr << "hello, world!" << endl;
}
```

If you want `print` to output to console or the default output, call

```
print(cout);
```

If you want it to write to a file, make an `ofstream`, and pass it to `print`:

```
ofstream file("hello.txt");
print(file);
```

Answer (score 2):

"Is there a way?": no... not without changing `print()` and/or adding more code in the caller.  When you say...

```
file << print();
```

...what's sent to the file stream is whatever's returned by `print()`.  As you've said `print()` is sending the desired output to `std::cout`, the return value's ostensibly not going to have anything we want in `file`, so unless it's an empty string it's best for the caller not to write `file << print();`.

Instead, the caller should divert output to `cout` to `file` before calling `print()`: [James' answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928789/redirecting-cout-into-file-c?rq=1) shows how that can be done.